# How to take this limit? $\lim_{x \to \infty}(x-ln^3(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Need to take the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(x-ln^3(x))$$
My idea is to come to indeterminate form $(\frac{0}{0})$, then use L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(x-ln^3(x))=ln\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{ln^3(x)}}=\left(\frac{0}{0}\right) = ln\left( \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{e^x}{e^{ln^3(x)}\cdot 3ln^2(x)\cdot \frac{1}{x}}\right)\right)=ln\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{e^x\cdot x}{e^{ln^3(x)} \cdot 3ln^2(x)}\right)$$
But I'm confused now. What I have to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write $x-ln^3x=x(1-\frac {ln^3x}{x})$ and use Hospital at $\frac {ln^3x}{x}$

Comment: When I use L'Hospitals in this case I get $\frac{(ln^3(x))'}{(x)'}=\frac{3ln^2x \cdot \frac{1}{x}}{1}=\frac{3ln^2x}{x}=(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$

Comment: Continue using it,until all things get clear

Comment: we have $ln^3x/x --3ln^2x/x--6lnx/x--6/x->0$ for $x->\infty$ and thus you desired lim goes to $\infty$

Comment: So $(6/x)$ approaches to $0$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: Wih Hospital we have that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac {ln^3x}{x})=0$ and thus $\lim_{x\to\infty}x(1-\frac {ln^3x}{x})=\infty$

Comment: I clearly understood your idea. It's works good. But I have only one question left: is it allowed to use L'Hospital's only at $\frac{3ln^2x}{x}$, but not at whole expression?

Comment: You can use it as long as you have $\infty/\infty$ and $0/0$ forms:)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* : $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-\ln^3x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}(e^t-t^3)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}-t^3\right)=\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to substitute $x=e^t$, which transforms your limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}(e^t-t^3)
$$
This is again of the form $\infty-\infty$, but much nicer, because the exponential is “bigger” than any polynomial. How can you do it? Rewrite the limit as
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}(e^t-t^3)=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^t/t^3-1}{1/t^3}.
$$
Now the denominator goes to $0$ (via positive values), while the numerator goes to $\infty$, which can be easily checked with l'Hôpital's theorem.